# I want to sort the related values that are obtained by contain in pagination (CakePHP4)

Tags: sorting, cakephp, pagination, associations, cakephp-4.x

Get the value of `contain` for the Slugs associated with the Posts model.
I want to sort them in order of the ID of the retrieved Slugs table.

in PostsController

```php
    /**
     * Index method
     *
     * @return \Cake\Http\Response|null|void Renders view
     */
    public function index()
    {
        $this->paginate = [
            'limit' => 10,
            'contain' => ['Slugs'],
            'order' => [
                'Slugs.id' => 'desc',
            ],
        ];
        $posts = $this->paginate($this->Posts);
        $this->set(compact('posts'));
    }
```

The retrieved values will be displayed in order of decreasing ID (asc).

ID in descending order.

Check the contents of the `$posts` value in `dd($posts)`.

```
0 => App\Model\Entity\Posts {#163 ▼
      #_accessible: array:6 [▶]
      #_fields: array:6 [▶]
      // ....
      id: 1
      title: "CakePHP"
      user_id: 1
      created: Cake\I18n\FrozenTime @1613560300 {#164 ▶}
      modified: Cake\I18n\FrozenTime @1613560300 {#195 ▶}
      users: array:2 [▼
        0 => App\Model\Entity\Slug {#213 ▼
          // ...
          id: 1
          name: "PHP7.2"
          [new]: false
          // ...
        }
        1 => App\Model\Entity\Slug {#224 ▼
          id: 2
          name: "CakePHP4"
          // ...
```

I have tried the following

```php
'order' => [
                'Posts.Slugs.id' => 'desc',
            ],
```

or

```php
$posts = $this->paginate($this->Posts->find()->order(['Slugs.id']);
```

How can I get the best results?

Comment: I'm not clear on why your posts even have multiple users. Since `posts` has a `user_id` column, I'd have expected a `belongsTo` relation there, and then you'd have a `user` property in the `Post` entity, not a `users` array. What's the database structure and relations here?

Comment: I'm sure... It's strange that there are so many users...

In this case, it's user-to-post, "believesTo".
It's a relationship with a large number of users.

But since you pointed it out and I noticed the discomfort...
I changed User to Slugs.

Answer (score 1):

So a Post has many Slugs, and when you load posts in the pagination (sorted by some field in the post), you want the slugs in those posts to be ordered by id? You should be able to do this with the `queryBuilder` parameter in the containment:

```
$this->paginate = [
    'limit' => 10,
    'contain' => [
        'Slugs' => [
            'queryBuilder' => function (Query $q) {
                return $q->order(['Slugs.id']);
            }
        ],
    ],
];
```

Comment: Thank you very much, Greg Schmidt.
This is exactly the answer I was looking for.
It helped me a lot.

Comment: sorry ``Argument 1 passed to App\Controller\SlugsController::App\Controller\{closure}() must be an instance of App\Controller\Query, instance of Cake\ORM\Query given, called in /htdocs/bbs/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/ORM/Association/Loader/SelectLoader.php on line 198`` <br>  I was unable to do so due to an error.

Comment: This is a standard namespace issue. You need to either specify the fully qualified name in the function prototype (`Cake\ORM\Query`) or else `use` that class name at the top of the file. Without those, it's assuming that `Query` is in your current namespace, `App\Controller`.